# PhpStorm - Search through all files like in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, phpstorm

In Notepad++ we are able to search for a specific keyword or regex which occurs in the content of all files of a specific directory.

Is this also possible in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this one, [Finding and Replacing Text in Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html). For Windows, it's `Ctrl+Shift+F`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this function in the edit menu Edit->Find->Find in Path